# Where can I d/l MS Powerpacks 10?

Tags: vb.net, powerpacks

I am not able to find site where to download ms Powerpacks 10, I use it with vb.net 2010.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs 10.0.0.0 is included with Visual Studio 2010.

By default located `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\VBPowerPacks\en\VisualBasicPowerPacksSetup.exe`

Comment: so how do I put it on the target machine?

Comment: First create an installer project. Right click on this project, go to properties, click the prerequisites button and finally check "Microsoft Visual Basic PowerPacks 10.0" If you select the option called "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application" when you build the setup project VisualBasicPowerPacksSetup.exe will be added to the directory of your compiled setup project output

Answer (score 4):

I beleive that 10.0 is not the real name but it is in fact 3.0. A link to download that can be found below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb735936

However from this post it would seem that it is included in VS2010 anyway!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/12/29/visual-basic-powerpacks-is-released-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2.aspx

Comment: well in my vs 2010 in references it says that it is version 10. And since on the target machine I am having a problem I want to rule out that having a different version of powerpacks is culprit. I did see somewhere that there is new version and it is 10 and that there are bug fixes (though no new features).

Answer (score 1):

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=145727&clcid=0x804

You can download from the above link.